# BlackBerry Internet Service for third party (non-native) apps

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

I have developed a small j2me application that communicates to the server and converted it to the .COD for BlackBerry devices. It doesn't run on my BIS connection, how do I run that app on my BlackBerry device over BIS connection. I have heard about Alliance program with RIM as its solution. How do I register for that and are there any alternatives to that program?

Comment: activated the BIS on your device ?

Comment: Yes I dont know what is the problem even though I have a BIS connection. However, it runs perfectly fine on WAP

Comment: you added the connection string for connecting the internet?

Comment: I have converted it from my JAD and JAR and there I had mentioned the required connection strings. Is it necessary to sign up(like the Alliance program of RIM) somewhere to let my app run over BIS connection? or can my app run directly on BB devices over BIS connection? Please guide.